# How to get values of one column without the aggregate column?

Tags: sql

I have this table:

| first_name | last_name | age | country |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | Doe | 31 | USA |
| Robert | Luna | 22 | USA |
| David | Robinson | 22 | UK |
| John | Reinhardt | 25 | UK |
| Betty | Doe | 28 | UAE |

How can I get only the names of the oldest per country?

When I do this query

```
SELECT first_name,last_name, MAX(age) 
FROM Customers
GROUP BY country
```

I get this result:

| first_name | last_name | MAX(age) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Betty | Doe | 31 |
| John | Reinhardt | 22 |
| John | Doe | 31 |

But I want to get only first name and last name without the aggregate function.

Comment: I'd expect an error. Which dbms are you using?

Comment: You also need to _specify_ the expected result. A [mcve].

Comment: I expect: Betty Doe ;
John Reinhard;
John Doe;

Comment: how do you group by country if you're selecting first_name, last_name?  which DBMS are you using?

Comment: When asking SQL questions, always tag the request with the DBMS you are using. The query you are showing is invalid according to the SQL standard. You say you are getting a result, though. So what is your DBMS that allows such query? I don't know any DBMS that doesn't through an error and even reports non-maximums with `MAX`.

Comment: As to the task itself: What result are you expecting when two or more persons share the same maximum age in a country?

Answer (score 2):

If window functions are an option, you can use `ROW_NUMBER` for this task.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY country ORDER BY age DESC) AS rn 
    FROM tab
)
SELECT first_name, last_name, age, country
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/L1KVSe5ccCpqndv2E3DAJ/0).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to get the oldest age per country first,

```
SELECT Country, MAX(age) AS MAX_AGE_IN_COUNTRY
FROM Customers
GROUP BY Country
```

With that, you want to match that back to the original table (aka a join) to see which names they match up to.

So, something like this perhaps:

```
SELECT Customers.*
FROM Customers
INNER JOIN 
(
  SELECT Country, MAX(age) AS MAX_AGE_IN_COUNTRY
  FROM Customers
  GROUP BY Country
) AS max_per_country_query
ON Customers.Country = max_per_country_query.Country
AND Customers.Age = max_per_country_query.MAX_AGE_IN_COUNTRY
```

If your database supports it, I prefer using the CTE style of handling these subqueries because it's easier to read and debug.

```
WITH cte_max_per_country AS (
  SELECT Country, MAX(age) AS MAX_AGE_IN_COUNTRY
  FROM Customers
  GROUP BY Country
)
SELECT Customers.*
FROM Customers C
INNER JOIN cte_max_per_country
ON C.Country = cte_max_per_country.Country
AND C.Age = cte_max_per_country.MAX_AGE_IN_COUNTRY
```

Comment: that will not work if there are two or more with the same age

Comment: The question said names (plural) so I assume they want all the ties as well.